# out of order processing of a Flux of input using Reactor

Tags: java, project-reactor

I am trying to figure out how to take a Flux that is a sequence of input data, in *parallel* run them through a blocking call that may reorder the sequence, then run the reordered data through a second single-threaded blocking call. The idea being that the final single-threaded call is recording the reordered parallel work output onto disk. The ultimate aim of what I am trying to do is that the parallel algorithm is a consensus algorithm that will determine the actual ordering of the data input. The single-threaded write is simulating processing things in the order determined by the consensus algorithm.

Looking at [this article](https://itnext.io/how-to-make-legacy-code-reactive-2debcb3d0a40) it suggests I should convert my blocking calls into Mono that run on a scheduler that either gives me parallel or single-threaded processing:

```java
public class BlockingRemoteCall {

    private final static Random r = new Random();

    private final static Scheduler scheduler = Schedulers.newParallel("myWebservice", 10);

    static private String blockingWebService(final String in) {
        try {
            // fakes blocking for up to a second
            Thread.sleep((long) (1000 * r.nextFloat()));
            System.out.println("webserver returned: "+in+" on "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        return in;
    }

    public static Mono<String> blockingMethodParallelThread(final String in) {
        return Mono.fromSupplier(() -> blockingWebService(in))
                .subscribeOn(scheduler);
    }
}

public class BlockingJournal {

    private final static Scheduler scheduler = Schedulers.newSingle("myJournal");

    private static String blockingWrite(String in){
        try {
            // fakes blocking for disk write
            Thread.sleep(5L);
            System.out.println("journal wrote: "+in+" on "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
        } catch (Exception e){
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        return in;
    }

    public static Mono<String> blockingMethodSingleThread(final String in) {
        return Mono.fromSupplier(() -> blockingWrite(in))
                .subscribeOn(scheduler);
    }
}
```

I have been trying to take a Flux of integers and somehow map or flatMap though these methods but I am unable to get anything to log. Here is my latest attempt:

```java
        final Scheduler parallelScheduler = Schedulers.newParallel("p");
        final Scheduler singleScheduler = Schedulers.single();

        Flux<String> flux = Flux.range(1, 10).map(i -> i.toString()).publishOn(parallelScheduler);

        Flux<String> pipeline = flux.map(s->{
            Mono<String> async = BlockingRemoteCall.blockingMethodParallelThread(s);
            String r1 = async.block();
            Mono<String> r2 = BlockingJournal.blockingMethodSingleThread(r1);
            return r2.block();
        });

        pipeline.subscribeOn(singleScheduler).doOnNext(System.out::println).blockLast();
```

That doesn't actually output anything but whenever I have been able to generate any output I only ever see `println` statements showing that the stream of data was processed in order on one thread. What I am hoping to see is that the arbitrary delays in the call to `blockingMethodParallelThread(s)` causing the sequence of input to be logged out-of-order.

How do I set things up so that a Flux of input (eventually bubbling up from reactor-netty input) can be processed in parallel, with reordering, then finally processed sequentially, preserving the reordering? where the reordering is due to making blocking calls in parallel? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few points here:

- Simply calling `publishOn(parallelScheduler)` does not make your `Flux` execute in parallel, it just means your sequential `Flux` will now publish on a parallel scheduler. Instead, you probably want to call `parallel()` to make it parallel, then specify `runOn()` with your chosen scheduler. (Similarly, calling `sequential()` on a parallel `Flux` will make it sequential again.)
- You almost certainly don't want to use a parallel scheduler for this work anyway - a bounded elastic scheduler would be a better choice (it's specifically designed for wrapping blocking IO.)
- There's not much point doing a `map()` call then blocking inside it - you may as well use `flatMap()` instead and just return the resulting publisher.
- There's no advantage here to creating new schedulers, you may as well just use the default ones.

So with those points in mind, your code becomes:

```
ParallelFlux<String> flux = Flux.range(1, 10).map(i -> i.toString()).parallel().runOn(Schedulers.elastic());

ParallelFlux<String> pipeline = flux.flatMap(s -> {
    Mono<String> async = BlockingRemoteCall.blockingMethodParallelThread(s);
    String r1 = async.block();
    return BlockingJournal.blockingMethodSingleThread(r1);
});

pipeline.sequential().doOnNext(System.out::println).blockLast();
```

...which will output the results out of order, as you expect.